# Codeigniter update functions updates all rows

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I'm learning codeigniter and did a todo application. I made a list of items and when checked they should update in the database from 0 to 1. This is my controller.

```
public function item_done($id){
    $this->db->from('list_items');
    $st="item_id='".$id."'";
    $this->db->where($st, NULL, FALSE);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if ($q->num_rows() == 0){
        redirect('main/restricted');
    } else {

    $this->db->update('list_items', array('item_done' => '1'));
            redirect('lists/view_list/');
        }
}
```

This is my database
[image: screen]

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, I forgot to add `where` this is how it should be `$this->db->where($st, NULL, FALSE)->update('list_items', array('item_done' => '1'));`

Answer (score 0):

u also try this

```
         $this->db->where('item_id',$st);
         $this->db->update('list_items', array('item_done' => '1'));
```